# How Gmail and other Mailservice providers must be taking there DB Backups?

Tags: database, database-backup, backup

Being Anxious, I thought of asking this question in SO, which will certainly help in getting an idea for how the big DB carriers take their backups.

How Gmail and other Mailservice providers must be taking there DB Backups?

Answer (score -1):

Google has it's own "database engine" called BigTable and a complete different architecture than any relational database you might know.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable for some initial idea.